# Own sort algorithm in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sorting

I have a table that stores hierarchical relationships.They stored as strings like 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2 ... Thus,when I need to sort them in hierarchical order I need to invoke my own sort function.Aren't I?But I think it is too long write own effective alghoritm (n*ln(n)).I want to use little function that just compares two values and use it with ORDER BY statement.Can I do this?Are there another ways to achive this goals?Thanks.

Comment: Can you pad the individual values out to a fixed length with zeroes, e.g. `0001.0001.0002`?

Comment: If each level is the same length then a text sort comes out in the right order.

Comment: yes,it's a pretty solution.Please make it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left padding each level with zeroes to a fixed length will allow a straightforward text sort.  With your sample values:

```
0001.0001
0001.0001.0001
0001.0001.0002
0001.0002
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
order by
    parsename(col,4)*1,
    parsename(col,3)*1,
    parsename(col,2)*1,
    parsename(col,1)*1
```

Comment: parsname function used for small strings but I can have very 'deep' strings - in advance unknown how 'deep' the hierarchy will be.